# How do I calculate the total of the qty and price in a dynamic created html table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help I have no Idea how to get the price and qty subtotals also I'm getting an undefined in the type field which is a drop down input I found this code here in this forum it calculates the total of the price column put not multiplying the qty and price to give a subtotal I'm very new at this jquery and java script How can I add a function that would multiply the qty * price

```js
function row(Id, Code, Client, Quantity, Price) {
   this.Id = Id;
   this.Code = Code;
   this.Client = Client;
   //this.DebitCredit = DebitCredit;
   this.Quantity = Quantity;
   this.Price = Price;
}

function model() {
  this.rows = [];
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  for (i = 0; i < mymodel.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(mymodel.rows[i].Id);
    if (mymodel.rows[i].Id == id) {
   mymodel.rows.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  draw();
});

$('#add').click(function() {
  mymodel.rows.push(new row(
    $('#Id').val(),
    $('#Code').val(),
    $('#Client').val(),
    Number($('#Quantity').val()),
    Number($('#Price').val())
  ))
  draw();
   });
})

function draw() {
  $('tbody').empty();
  var totalQuantity = 0;
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $.each(mymodel.rows, function(i, row) {
  totalQuantity += row.Quantity;
  totalPrice += row.Price;
  var myrow = '<tr>'
  $.each(row, function(key, value) {
    myrow += '<td>' + value + '</td>'
  });
  myrow += '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="' + row.Id + '" value="X"/></td>'
  myrow += '<tr>'
  $('tbody').append(myrow);
  });
  $('#totalQuantity').text(totalQuantity)
  $('#totalPrice').text(totalPrice)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <style>
   
  </style>
  </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <table class="table table-condensed">
   <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Part #</td>
    <td>Part Name</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7>Total Quantity:
   <span id="totalQuantity"></span> Total Price:
   <span id="totalPrice"></span>
    </td>

  </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>

 <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="id">Part #:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="PartName">Part Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Code">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="type">Type:</label>
  <select name="type" id="cliente" class="form-control">
     <option value="" selected="selected"">Please Select..</option>
     <option value="Code">Code</option>
     <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Quantity">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Price">Price:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Price">
   </div>
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="add" id="add" />
 </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a small detail. When setting the total price, you were using this code `totalPrice += row.Price;`. All you needed to do, was changing the code, so that instead of just adding up the price, you would multiply it by the row quantity, 
`totalPrice += row.Price * row.Quantity;`.

```js
function row(Id, Code, Client, Quantity, Price) {
   this.Id = Id;
   this.Code = Code;
   this.Client = Client;
   //this.DebitCredit = DebitCredit;
   this.Quantity = Quantity;
   this.Price = Price;
    this.Total = Quantity * Price;
 }

 function model() {
   this.rows = [];
 }

 var mymodel = new model();

 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("body").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  for (i = 0; i < mymodel.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(mymodel.rows[i].Id);
    if (mymodel.rows[i].Id == id) {
   mymodel.rows.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  draw();
   });

   $('#add').click(function() {
  mymodel.rows.push(new row(
    $('#Id').val(),
    $('#Code').val(),
    $('#cliente').val(),
    Number($('#Quantity').val()),
    Number($('#Price').val())
  ))
  draw();
   });
 })

 function draw() {
   $('tbody').empty();
   var totalQuantity = 0;
   var totalPrice = 0;
   $.each(mymodel.rows, function(i, row) {
  totalQuantity += row.Quantity;
  totalPrice += row.Price * row.Quantity;
  var myrow = '<tr>';
  $.each(row, function(key, value) {
    myrow += '<td>' + value + '</td>'
  });
  myrow += '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="' + row.Id + '" value="X"/></td>'
  myrow += '<tr>'
  $('tbody').append(myrow);
   });
   $('#totalQuantity').text(totalQuantity)
   $('#totalPrice').text(totalPrice)
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <style>
   
  </style>
  </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <table class="table table-condensed">
   <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Part #</td>
    <td>Part Name</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7>Total Quantity:
   <span id="totalQuantity"></span> Total Price:
   <span id="totalPrice"></span>
    </td>

  </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>

 <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="id">Part #:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="PartName">Part Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Code">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="type">Type:</label>
  <select name="type" id="cliente" class="form-control">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
     <option value="Code">Code</option>
     <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Quantity">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Price">Price:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Price">
   </div>
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="add" id="add" />
 </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Please, let me know if you need anything else. Also, there was a typo in `#Cliente`, the c was on lower case, so I changed it to `#cliente`.

Comment: thank you how to i get it to show this in the actual table row and have it calculate that column maybe a total amount column

Comment: You mean a total per row?

Comment: Ok, I edited the code, so that now you can get to see the total per row.

Comment: Thank you this work perfect just how I wanted it to do your great

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark my answer as correct and up vote! :) Those points are always nice.